# Conditions that defines a subspace of $S$ of a $V$, can be express as a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is it true that the conditions that define any proper subspace $S$ of a vector space $V$, with $\dim(V)<+\infty$, can be express as a homogeneous system of linear equation?

Let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: e^{x}=1\}$, the condition that defines $S$ is the non linear equation $e^{x}=1$, but it is equivalent to $x=0$, so $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x=0\}$ ($S$ is clearly a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$). Another expample: let
$$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x^2-2x y+y^2=0\}$$

In this case, the condition that defines the elements of $S$ is $x^2-2x y+y^2=0$ witch is equivalent to the equation $(x-y)^2=0\ \ \ \to \ \ \ x-y=0$, so $S$ can be express as $$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x-y=0\}$$ and it's easy to prove that it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

*It seems to me* that the response is positive if $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, but what can I say if $V$ is a polynomial vector space, or a matrix vector space? I know, maybe it's a silly question, but I would like to know that it's true or not. Thanks.

Comment: That there is non linear system that it's solution    form a subspace does not contradict anything.

Comment: @dmtri, sorry but I don't understand how your comment can help me. :(

Comment: In your second paragraph you write, If I understand correctly, that some non linear system of equations have solutions that form a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$, which is ok. That is why I wrote that.